# How to put ResultSet to List of Array

Tags: java, arrays, list, refactoring, resultset

I am trying to put ResultSet into List< Object[]>. Here is my code

```
List<CSVRaportDescription[]> result = new ArrayList<>();
List<CSVRaportDescription> csvRaportDescList = new ArrayList<>();
ResultSet resultSet = dataSource.executeQuery(query.toString().replace("?", dayList.toString()));
resultSet.forEach(row->{
    csvRaportDescList.add(new CSVRaportDescription(row.getObject("value")));
});
CSVRaportDescription[] csvRaportArray = csvRaportDescList.toArray(new CSVRaportDescription[csvRaportDescList.size()]);
result.add(csvRaportArray);
```

Is any way to make it faster?

First I put resultset into List< Object> then to Object[] and at the end I add it to List< Object[]>. It seems to be the longest way however I can not refactor it to better quality.

Comment: `ResultSet` doesn't have a `forEach()`?... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html So what type is this? And what Java version?

Comment: It is Java 8 and there is forEach() and I use it in line 4th.

Comment: https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/ResultSet.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you stream the result `List`, you can skip the intermediate lists.

```
CSVRaportDescription[] result = resultSet.all().stream()
    .map(row -> new CSVRaportDescription(row.getObject("value")))
    .toArray(CSVRaportDescription[]::new);
return Collections.singletonList(result);
```

Whether this is faster, you'll have to measure.

Comment: It is faster for sure but I can not just return because I have iteration there. I didnt paste whole code.

Comment: Overall it helps me a lot. You fix my problem. Thank you so much :)